# Is it possible to get Facebook Messenger-style camera integration using Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, camera

Facebook Messenger lets you send pictures in a way that I haven't seen done in any other app before. Instead of opening the default camera-app or going full-screen camera, they open a camera-view in the space where the keyboard usually resides. Then you just touch an icon overlaid on the viewfinder to take and send the picture. Is it possible to do this using Cordova/PhoneGap?